# Передача JSON из PHP в NodeJS

Tags: php, json, node.js

Отправляю из PHP JSON

```
$data_json = json_encode(["test" => 123, "text" => "tex[]t"]);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 100);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Принимаю в NODEJS

```
app.post('/test', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

В итоге получается ерунда какая то

```
{ '{"test":123,"text":"tex': [ '' ] }
```

без квадратных скобок в text

```
{ '{"test":123,"text":"text"}': '' }
```

Что надо сделать с квадратными скобками в тесте, как то их экранировать или заголовки какие то добавить, не могу понять.

---

Все ребят, добавил и заработало:

> установил: npm install body-parser

```
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: смотрите на middleware node,  который тело парсит

Comment: добавьте заголовок content type, скорей всего просто первым попавшимся способом парсится тело

Comment: По умолчанию req.body нет. Значит у есть какие-то middleware для парсинга. Весь код в студию

Comment: Спасибо заработало